# is keyword does not work with inheritance  (  baseClass is DerivedObject ) = true  "How could I avoid that"

Tags: c#, inheritance, polymorphism

I have the classes

```
Interface IVehicle
{
    int numberOfWheels;
    bool CanCross(string obstacle);
    // etc
}

class Car : IVehicle
{
    public int numberOfWheels = 4;
    public bool CanCross(string obstacle)
    {
       switch(obstacle) 
       {
          case "river":
              return false;
          case "grass":
              return true;
          // etc
       }
    }
}

class RaceCar: Car
{
    public int numberOfWheels = 4;
    public bool CanCross(string obstacle)
    {
       switch(obstacle) 
       {
          case "river":
              return false;
          case "grass":
              return false;
          // etc
       }
    }
}
```

**And then I have the method:**

```
 public object Foo(IVehicle vehicle, string obstacle)
 {                              
      if(vehicle.CanCross(obstacle)==false)
      {
          if(vehicle is Car)
             return Foo(new RaceCar(), obstacle);
          else if(vehicle is RaceCar)
             return Foo(new OldCar(), obstacle);
         // etc
          else
             return null;
      }

      // implementation

      return someObject;
 }
```

note that if the vehicle cannot cross the obstacle I recursively call the same method again in order to try with a different vehicle. **My question is** why if vehicle = SpeedCar then `if (vehicle is Car)` evaluates to **true** ?  Probably because it inherits from it. How could I check if the vehicle is a SpeedCar but not a Car. I now I could call the ToString() method then do a regex but then if I rename my classes I will break my code...

In other words if the vehicle that I pass cannot cross and it happens to be a Car or SpeedCar I will go into an infinite loop...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> How could I check if the vehicle is a SpeedCar but not a Car

```
vehicle.GetType() == typeof(SpeedCar)
```

Comment: @TonoNam: you're welcome. By the way, you really shouldn't hide inherited member `CanCross`. Make it `virtual` and use `override` keyword to override behavior in descendant classes. Also, to throw away ugly type checking, you can add a virtual property `Car.ReplaceWithCar`.

Comment: Then your method `Foo` will look like this: `if (!car.CanCross(obstacle)) { return car.ReplaceWithCar != null ? Foo(car.ReplaceWithCar) : null; }`

Comment: Thanks I will make it virtual or abstract.

Answer (score 19):

You can do this using the `is` operator - in fact, it's somewhat faster than using `GetType()`.

Your inheritance hierarchy is `IVehicle`->`Car`->`RaceCar`, so anything that's a `RaceCar` will also be a `Car` and an `IVehicle`. If you first test for the base class, your code will never reach more specific test because the base class will match anyway - this is why you had problems with it.

The right way to test in a scenario where you need to do different things for classes in an inheritance chain is to test more specific (more derived) classes first and test base classes last.

```
if (vehicle is RaceCar)
{
    // code
}
else if (vehicle is Car)
{
    // code
}
else
{
    // code
}
```

[Dennis' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12483409/682404) is correct that using virtual functions simplifies these situations because you can avoid these kind of tests in most cases when you have virtual functions - simply all derived classes can provide their own implementation of a function (or rely on the base implementation without overriding it when appropriate). If there's no point in having a base implementation you can use the `abstract` keyword to indicate that derived classes must provide an implementation without relying on the base class. Those derived classes then use `override` to implement such abstract functions.

Answer (score 8):

While others have answered your question already, I would like to suggest you another approach for generating Foos.
Use [Polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)) to get rid of the endless if-else chain (or switch statement) and let the vehicles implement a method `CreateAlternateVehicle`

```
public interface IVehicle
{
    bool CanCross(string obstacle);

    IVehicle CreateAlternativeVehicle();
}
```

A `Car` would create a `RaceCar`, a `RaceCar` an `OldCar` and so on. The last car in the chain could return `null`. As an example, the class `Car` would implement it like this:

```
public IVehicle CreateAlternativeVehicle()
{
    return new RaceCar();
}
```

Then your Foo creation becomes

```
public object Foo(IVehicle vehicle, string obstacle)
{                              
    if(!vehicle.CanCross(obstacle)) {
        var altVehicle = vehicle.CreateAlternativeVehicle();
        if (altVehicle == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return Foo(altVehicle, obstacle);
    }
    ...
}
```

Very often, if-else chains and switch statements are a hint, that something could be done in a more object-oriented way.

Answer (score -2):

You should just check if(vehicle is RaceCar)