# Class inheritance design with protected methods and run time base handlers

Tags: c#, inheritance, design-patterns

Using C#, I got a class called BaseConfigurations which handles CRUD operations. This class also contains a protected method which is used inside the CRUD handling methods:

```
public class BaseConfigurations : ICRUDHandler
{
    public virtual bool CreateSetting(string someData)
    {
        //some logic
        ProtectedMethod();
        //more logic
    }
    
    protected virtual void ProtectedMethod() { ... }
}
```

Now there's a different version which can handle the CRUD operation a bit different:

```
public class BaseConfigurationsV2 : BaseConfigurations { ... }
```

There are 2 instances of `BaseConfigurations` and `BaseConfigurationsV2` living at the same time and should be invoked based on some logic I have.

Now there's another class which handles specifically secret data:

```
public class SecretConfigurations : BaseConfigurations
{
   public ICRUDHandler _crudHandler;
   public SecretConfigurations(ICRUDHandler handler) 
   { 
      _crudHandler = handler; //this handler gets either the instance of `BaseConfigurations` or `BaseConfigurationsV2` 
   }

   public override bool CreateSetting(string data)
   {
      _crudHandler.CreateSetting(data);
      //adds additional logic
   }

   public override void ProtectedMethod() { ... }
}
```

My problem here is that because the ICRUDHandler which SecretConfigurations receives is either BaseConfigurations or BaseConfigurationsV2, it doesn't know the protected method which was overriden in SecretConfigurations and doesn't invoke it.

The easy way to fix it is to probably just make another class of `SecretConfigurationsV2` which will derive from BaseConfigurationsV2 and then have the handler be initialized to either `SecretConfigurations` or `SecretConfigurationsV2`, but that involves code duplication.

How would you design a fix for this issue?

Comment: This may be a better fit for https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/ than SO, since there are a lot of opinions on software design. A general recommendation is to try to avoid inheritance, and if you need to use it, make sure to follow Liskov substitution principle. So think if some other design might be better. Code duplication is not *that* bad, especially if the context the code is used in is different.

Comment: I think this problem arises because this is actually a mix of inheritance _and_ composition. `SecretConfigurations` **is-a** `BaseConfigurations` as well as **has-a** `ICRUDHandler` ... have you considered that? ( => "Back to the drawing board" )

Comment: That's why I asked this question so I can know how to fix this issue

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is that I would remove inheritance in `SecretConfigurations` because you are injecting `ICRUDHandler` into its constructor:

```
public class SecretConfigurations
{
   public ICRUDHandler _crudHandler;
   public SecretConfigurations(ICRUDHandler handler) 
   { 
      _crudHandler = handler; //this handler gets either the instance of 
          // `BaseConfigurations` or `BaseConfigurationsV2` 
   }
   
    public bool CreateSetting(string someData) =>
        _crudHandler.CreateSetting(someData);
}
```

And try to give another name to the class to avoid unclearness for future users of this class. E.g.: `CrudHandler`

Comment: But that doesn't solve the issue of the protected method which are defined in BaseConfigurations and is overriden in SecretConfigurations. That protected method is called inside the public method of BaseConfigurations, so how will it know to dynamically invoke the overriden method when using composition with handlers?

Comment: @CodeMonkey Maybe I didn't catch something, but method can be called just by invoking it `_crudHandler.CreateSetting(someData)`. I've added the call to my code snippet. Please, see my updated answer

Comment: but INSIDE CreateSetting there's a call to a protected method which should be invoked dynamically

Comment: @CodeMonkey what do you mean by `dynamically`? Do you mean that you want to do different actions based on knowledge what class is injected `BaseConfigurations` or `BaseConfigurationsV2`?

Comment: Inside CreateSetting there's a call to a protected method. It's being overridden by SecretConfigurations so it should determine if to call the one from BaseConfigurations or SecretConfigurations

Comment: @CodeMonkey am I right that you want to call `BaseConfigurations.CreateSetting()` or `BaseConfigurationsV2.CreateSetting()`  in 
`SecretConfigurations.CreateSetting()` ? Or you want to know what concrete implementation is injected to `ICRUDHandler _crudHandler` in `SecretConfigurations` class?

Comment: Inside CreateSetting there's a call to SomeMethod(). SomeMethod is defined in BaseConfigurations and overridden in SecretConfigurations. I want that whenever CreateSettings is invoked, then the correct SomeMethod() will also be invoked based if the invoker is a BaseConfigurations or a SecretConfigurations

Comment: @CodeMonkey ok, I think you you can use `is` operator to understand `BaseConfigurations` or `BaseConfigurationsV2`. E.g.: `if (_crudHandler  is BaseConfigurations) { // ... do what you want }` and `if (_crudHandler  is BaseConfigurationsV2) { // ... do what you want }`. [Read more here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12483593)

Comment: But it doesn't depend on BaseConfigurationsV2. It's true that the handler can be BaseConfigurationsV2 but the call itself depends if its called for BaseConfigurations or SecretConfigurations. If you want, I got another question which is from a different perspective for this problem:

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/450967/adding-a-new-version-of-a-service-to-live-alongside-the-previous-one

Comment: @CodeMonkey could you show examples with code snippets where you run with BaseConfiguration or SecretConfiguration? Examples where you are stuck